# Windows 7 failure (0xc0000428)

Tags: windows-7, boot, freeze, bsod

I have an old computer, the configuration is: Pentium D Dual Core, 1 GB Ram, 250GB HD.

The error is intermittent: sometimes the computer freeze during Windows startup and sometimes freeze after 15 or 30 minutes of use.

First, it shows a BSOD (extremely fast) and after reboot, it shows this error (sorry, it's in portuguese, but the status code is 0xc0000428):

[image: first]

After one minute, the screen starts displaying this error:

[image: second]

Things I've done:

- Replaced the power supply unit;
- Replaced the surge protector;
- Replaced the VGA cable;
- Repaired Windows by CD (`bootrec /fixMBR`, `bootrec /fixBoot`, `bootrec /rebuildBCD`)
- Loaded without digital signature (pressing F8).

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried replacing the RAM?

[This guy](http://www.sevenforums.com/bsod-help-support/188330-bsod-win-7-startup-trying-pinpoint-cause.html) found doing so helpful, and intermittent issues including graphics buffer corruption sounds a lot like memory issues to me.